# 502 Bad Gateway. Django Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I deployed my django project in GAE and I get the 502 Bad Gateway error on all pages except the main one. The previous version was working, but is not working since I added API calls for storage (storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage). I added environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in both settings.py and app.yaml. Log shows this error:

```
[error] 32#32: *111 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/accounts/login/", host: "xxxx.appspot.com", referrer: "https://xxxx.appspot.com/"
```

All is working in local, so that message is all I have.
I tried things from google groups and other stackoverflow questions but it's not working.

Thank you.

Comment: You say that you are doing API calls to storage so you are using [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) or [this]( https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview)? Or are you using a client library? Could you please update your question with the code you are using? Thank you.

Comment: I'm using django storages library for google cloud storage. The problem was in the credentials json file. I only make it works putting that file inside the django project and referencing it in app.yaml

Comment: Just to clarify, when you moved the credentials file to the Django project, the application started working correctly? Was that credentials file for your own account o for a service account you were using for this app?

Comment: @RodrigoC. Yes, I had a reference link to google cloud storage, but it doesn't work that way. I created a service account

Answer (score 8):

`gcloud app logs tail -s default` tells you the error message, so make sure you check the output. Mine was `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.`

Some other mistakes I made were:

- wrong value for `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and `DATABASES` in `settings.py`
- wrong value for `static_dir` in `app.yaml`
- absence of `main.py`

Comment: "absence of main.py" did the trick for me. @Bartleby this was really helpful!

Comment: What kind of main.py filed did you add to the project?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a couple of steps to solve your issues with Django and App Engine.

You mentioned that you added the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to both the `settings.py` and `app.yaml` files. You should also add it to the system you are using to deploy your app. Use this command for this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[path to the .json credentials file]
```

Apart from that, make sure the Django version you are using is newer than 1.2 or 1.3, as those are no longer supported by Google Cloud.

You can have more information regarding how to configure Django in an App Engine application [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development), regarding how to configure the `app.yaml` and `settings.py` files (or another file you have for your settings).

Depending on which version of Python you are using, it is better to deploy in a [standard](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) environment if you are using Python 2 or a [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) environment if you use Python 3. The links I provided here are tutorials for better understanding how to use Django with App Engine. Once you test these tutorials, you can adapt them to your code and

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, App Engine requires you to add main.py on your root directory. You can add the code from the docs into that file:

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

from [APP_NAME].wsgi import application

# App Engine by default looks for a main.py file at the root of the app
# directory with a WSGI-compatible object called app.
# This file imports the WSGI-compatible object of your Django app,
# application from mysite/wsgi.py and renames it app so it is discoverable by
# App Engine without additional configuration.
# Alternatively, you can add a custom entrypoint field in your app.yaml:
# entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
app = application
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).